# Как прописать запросы в PostgREST с паролем?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, api

Используется БД **Postgres 13 и REST** для него **PostgREST**. Есть 2 пользователя A и B внутри PG, у которых равные права. К PostgREST (API) могут делать запросы все, кто хочет сейчас.

**Вопрос**: как сделать ограничения по паролю или передаче ключа. То есть, если идет запрос без секретного ключа, то запрос игнорируется, а если с ним, то пройдет. В документации не разобрался по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типавая схема - авторизация с JWT https://postgrest.org/en/v4.1/tutorials/tut1.html

Если хочется просто по паролю, то проще закрыть через прокси на nginx.

Comment: Сделали уже как там. Спасибо! А вот если обратиться на localhost:3000, то выводится какая-то служебная инфа. Как ее закрыть?

Comment: Это другой сервис скорее всего